# Is it possible to post a request to Microsoft Bot?

Tags: botframework

I want to post a request to my Microsoft Bot from Postman ( but until now it was unsuccessful) and after that I will choose a channel (Skype, Mail, SMS etc.) and sent those message to selected channel.
Is it possible and what kind of headers they need in Postman ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, you need to use the DirectLine connection and then call your bot like any API